# Unable to use model properties during compile time in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, generics

I am developing an application in Asp.net MVC core in which i using a generic interface which is as below :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TKeyType> where TEntity : class where TKeyType : struct
{
    TEntity Add(TEntity entity);
}
```

And below is the implementation of it.

```
  public class EntityRepository<TEntity, TKeyType> : IRepository<TEntity, TKeyType> where TEntity : class where TKeyType : struct
{
    protected readonly DrinkDbContext Context;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public EntityRepository(DrinkDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Futher, I am inheriting EntityRepository class in ShoppingCartRepository which is as below :

```
 public class ShoppingCartRepository<ShoppingCartItem, Int32> : EntityRepository<ShoppingCartItem, Int32>
    where ShoppingCartItem : class where Int32 : struct
{
    public ShoppingCartRepository(DrinkDbContext context) : base(context) { }

    public override ShoppingCartItem Add(ShoppingCartItem entity)
    {
        base.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

and able to see the populated properties of a class in a method at the runtime.  Please find the screenshot as below :

[image]

But when try to use those properties at compile time, i am unable to see those properties. Please find the screenshot as below.

[image]

How can i access the properties of **ShoppingCartItem** which is passed in Add method as a parameter ?

Comment: Although yout question is semi-complete and understandable. Please post the code for better clarity and for us to copy it https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I will say this though I believe your issue is with the generic constraints.

Comment: @panoskarajohn : Please find the updated question with code.

Comment: `public class ShoppingCartRepository : EntityRepository<ShoppingCartItem, Int32>` Change your code to this. ShoppingCartItem was viewed as a class as a generic variable. Since you need specific functionality you do not need to make the ShoppingCartRepository generic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `ShoppingCartRepository` is viewed as a generic.
`ShoppingCartRepository<ShoppingCartItem,int>` -> In this scenario `ShoppingCartItem` is of type `class` which you have constrained it.

It is like writing `ShoppingCartRepository<T,int>`. So your ShoppingCartItem is not viewed as a type `ShoppingCartItem` but as a generic of type `T` where `T : class`.

So `class` does not have access to `ShoppingCartItem`'s properties inside the `Add` method.

Update to this:

`public class ShoppingCartRepository : EntityRepository<ShoppingCartItem, Int32>`

This make your `ShoppingCartRepository` non generic.
I do not think you want the `ShoppingCartRepository` generic, since you are specifying implementation for `ShoppingCartItem`.

With the above change. You should have access to the `ShoppingCartItem` properties inside the `Add` method.

Comment: Thanks for update. I am able to access the model properties now.  Earlier in Startup.cs  class i have defined dependencies like this   : 
         public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(ShoppingCartRepository<,>));
        }
But now on changing to  services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(ShoppingCartRepository)); I am facing dependency injection issue. Pl help how to specify dependencies  for  ShoppingCartRepository.

Comment: Changing DI has not solved my issue. Your solution helped me that's why i have up voted it.   I have updated my code as you have suggested but now in Startup.cs while configuring services i am facing issue . Please see as below : 

      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // This line is giving compile time error
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,>), (ShoppingCartRepository<,>));
        }

Comment: @semwal Your issue with DI is out of scope. But I would go ahead register it either as Self() or create an interface for it. Honestly you need to read more about repo pattern. You have created a Generic solution and then you went ahead and inherited from it. THis is very confusing at least to me. Julie Lerman is an authority on EF patterns. Research her. Also if you still have issues. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @semwal the purpose of a generic solution is to not have to create a specific one meaning you could do sth like this `IRepository<ShippingItem,int>` and not create specific implementations. What you have done will lead to issues. Imagine adding a new repository with some othe object, how would you regiister it? You need to rethink this. In my opinion you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you help me on DI.    I have updated my code as you have suggested but now in Startup.cs while configuring services i am facing issue .  Please see as below : 

      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        // This is giving compile time error.
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,>), (ShoppingCartRepository<,>));
        }
How to define DI for ShoppingCartRepository now ?